# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Class'

Tags: python, roc, auc

Here is a sample of my data set:

```
   Pat_ID  Flare_Up  Demo1     Demo2     Demo3     Demo4  Demo5     Demo6  DisHis1  DisHis1Times  DisHis2    ...     Dis6Treat  Dis7  RespQues1  ResQues1a  ResQues1b  ResQues1c  ResQues2a  SmokHis1  SmokHis2  SmokHis3  SmokHis4
0       1         0      1  0.246004  0.391931  0.237792      0  0.443526        0      0.000000        0    ...             1     0    0.12623     0.1032     0.2439     0.0597        0.0  0.411765  0.263620  0.482759    0.1875
1       2         1      1  0.225851  0.268012  0.268481      0  0.286501        0      0.000000        1    ...             1     0    0.60707     0.3808     0.8637     0.4949        0.1  0.117647  0.098418  0.624138    0.0000
2       3         0      0  0.342599  0.476945  0.296468      1  0.159780        1      0.166667        1    ...             0     0    0.77541     0.6318     1.0000     0.6570        0.3  0.035294  0.020211  0.510345    0.0000

[3 rows x 62 columns]
```

My code to traverse through that data set and print `ROC` is:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report, roc_curve, roc_auc_score
import itertools

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes, normalize=True, title='Confusion matrix', cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    """
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
#    else:
#        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

#    print(cm)

    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, cm[i, j],
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
    plt.show()

def show_data(cm, print_res = 0):
    tp = cm[1,1]
    fn = cm[1,0]
    fp = cm[0,1]
    tn = cm[0,0]
    if print_res == 1:
        print('Precision =     {:.3f}'.format(tp/(tp+fp)))
        print('Recall (TPR) =  {:.3f}'.format(tp/(tp+fn)))
        print('Fallout (FPR) = {:.3e}'.format(fp/(fp+tn)))
    return tp/(tp+fp), tp/(tp+fn), fp/(fp+tn)

df = pd.read_csv("datasource/DevelopmentData.csv")
print(df.head(3))
y = np.array(df.Class.tolist())     #classes: 1..fraud, 0..no fraud
df = df.drop('Class', 1)
df = df.drop('Time', 1)     # optional
df['Amount'] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df['Amount'].values.reshape(-1,1))    #optionally rescale non-normalized column
X = np.array(df.as_matrix())   # features
```

A class of 0 means that the transaction was in order, and a class of 1 means that the transaction was fraudulent.
When I run my code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "finalindex.py", line 54, in <module>
    y = np.array(df.Class.tolist())     #classes: 1..fraud, 0..no fraud
  File "C:\Users\kulkaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4376, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Class'
```

How can I fix that error? Do I need to change column names according to data set?

Comment: I don't know anything about `roc` or `auc`, but is `DataFrame` supposed to have a `Class` attribute?  If it doesn't, you will always get that error.

Comment: Ummm... yes, I guess `Dataframe` has `Class` attribute. The author of this link (https://www.kaggle.com/dstuerzer/optimized-logistic-regression) has used it and it is working fine with his code.

Comment: It is good that you mentioned this!  I noticed his database has a column named "Class".  See my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] The author of this
>   link ([kaggle.com/dstuerzer/optimized-logistic-regression](http://kaggle.com/dstuerzer/optimized-logistic-regression)) has used it
>   and it is working fine with his code.

In the link you mentioned, [example](https://www.kaggle.com/dstuerzer/optimized-logistic-regression), the author's database has a column named "Class" but the database that you have shown does not.  As a result, the *Class* attribute does not exist in your database and therefore cannot be accessed.

**Dominik Stuerzer**:

> ```
>    Time        V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7  \
> 0   0.0 -1.359807 -0.072781  2.536347  1.378155 -0.338321  0.462388  0.239599   
> 1   0.0  1.191857  0.266151  0.166480  0.448154  0.060018 -0.082361 -0.078803   
> 2   1.0 -1.358354 -1.340163  1.773209  0.379780 -0.503198  1.800499  0.791461   
>
>          V8        V9  ...         V21       V22       V23       V24  \
> 0  0.098698  0.363787  ...   -0.018307  0.277838 -0.110474  0.066928   
> 1  0.085102 -0.255425  ...   -0.225775 -0.638672  0.101288 -0.339846   
> 2  0.247676 -1.514654  ...    0.247998  0.771679  0.909412 -0.689281   
>
>         V25       V26       V27       V28  Amount  Class  
> 0  0.128539 -0.189115  0.133558 -0.021053  149.62      0  
> 1  0.167170  0.125895 -0.008983  0.014724    2.69      0  
> 2 -0.327642 -0.139097 -0.055353 -0.059752  378.66      0  
>
> [3 rows x 31 columns]
> ```
>
> A class of 0 means that the transaction was in order, and a class of 1
>   means that the transaction was fraudulent. From personal experience we
>   expect frauds to make up only a tiny fraction of all transactions.
>   Indeed, in this dataset, for every fraud there are almost 600
>   non-fraudulent transactions: [...]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
df = df.drop(['Class'],axis=1)
df = df.drop(['Time'],axis=1) # optional
```

Comment: when I added your code and ran it, it threw this error: `Invalid syntax`. So I used `df = df.drop('Class', axis=1)` and `df = df.drop('Time', axis=1)`. But I got same error as mentioned in question

Comment: I have updated the answer please do try, make sure you have the column named 'Class'

Comment: I modified like this: `df = df.drop(['Demo1'],axis=1)
df = df.drop(['Demo2'],axis=1)`. But after running updated code, I'm still getting `DataFrame has no attribute Class` error

Comment: Print df.columns check weather column named 'Class' exists.

Comment: Output of `print(df.columns)` is given in this link: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/kkCei96z. There is no column named as `Class`.

Comment: As there is  NO column named 'Class',  code is about to  to drop the column named "Class", that's why the error is occuring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180737/discussion-between-ajay-kulkarni-and-emkay).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
y = np.array(df['Class'].tolist())
```